# Styled Components toggle display: none / block on another component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to pass display: none / block with OnClick handler, to hide the
 component when clicking on the  component
I've been struggling for hours trying various options to no avail, is there any option to do so?
Here is an example of the code on stackblitz to test
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ru54gk?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using regular conditional rendering based on `toggle`?

Something like this:

`{toggle && <ColorPicker />}`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e4wnzk

Comment: Brilliant, I never even thought of it. Much appreciated